# Thread pool and db connection pool with Task.WaitAll vs Task.WhenAll - under heavy load

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, async-await, connection-pooling

I have 2 methods that get data from DB.

```
var data1 = await GetData1();
var data2 = await GetData2();
```

in order to make this 2 calls simultaneously, I did like this:

```
var data1Task = GetData1();
var data2Task = GetData2();
Task.WaitAll(data1Task, data2Task);
```

... however this exhausted my connection pool (**under heavy load**, about 4k requests per minute).

When I refactored to `Task.WhenAll`, all works fine:

```
var data1Task = GetData1();
var data2Task = GetData2();
await Task.WhenAll(data1Task, data2Task);
```

I'd like to ask what WaitAll (blocking thread) has to do with connection pool being exhausted?
I understand that WaitAll block thread from threads pool, but what it has to do with connections pool?

EDIT:
GetData1 & 2 methods looks like this:

```
public async Task<List<DbModel>> GetData1(long customerId)
{
    string sql = $@"
    SELECT          
        id as Id, 
        title as Title
        ... more cols here
                
    FROM 
        table_1
    LEFT JOIN 
        table_2
    ON 
        id = another_id
    WHERE 
        id = @CustomerIdDbParam 
    ";

    List<DbModel> dbResponse = null;

    using (IDbConnection connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString.Value))
    {
        dbResponse = (await connection.QueryAsync<DbModel>(sql,
        new
        {
            CustomerIdDbParam = customerId
        })).ToList();
    }

    return dbResponse;
}
```

The exception I've been getting was:

1. timeout:

`System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out. at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Authenticate`
and
`System.TimeoutException: The operation has timed out. at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout`

2. pool exhausted:

`System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (The operation has timed out.) (The connection pool has been exhausted, either raise MaxPoolSize (currently 200) or Timeout (currently 15 seconds))`

Comment: How do you know that the connection pool was exhausted (with the `Task.WaitAll` approach)? Is there some global property that returns the available connections in the pool?

Comment: Exceptions were thrown saying it was exhausted, and also my DB connections count chart spiked from 100 to 700

Comment: Hmmm... This doesn't sound normal. Can we see the code of the `GetData1` and `GetData2` methods?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I just extended my initial question. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see anything strange in the code. I would suggest to open the profiler of the database server, and watch the incoming requests. You could find suspicious things happening there.

Comment: You are calling that in a loop? I mean how two queries can exhaust 200 connection pool?

Comment: If you're generating a large load on your server and blocking on some threads, is it possible that `ThreadPool` is not creating new threads fast enough to run the continuations that release the connection? It's just a theory but I would expect lower thread usage with the `await` form. Could you maybe add a logging statement to check if the connection release code is actually being run? Could you also provide more details on how you test this as requested above?

Comment: My prod server got around 4k requests per minute. Looks like they (the db connections) are not being released to serve another requests. When I changed to "WhenAll" all works fine.

Comment: But there's no connection release code... It's just "using" statement which per my knowledge should call Dispose and handle it on it's own.

Comment: Yes, but that dispose is scheduled after the `await` and needs a thread to run on. With `await WhenAll`, you release the initiating thread whilst with `WaitAll` it stays blocked, causing increased pressure on the `ThreadPool` in order to run the `Dispose` once the database query completes.

Comment: So you mean there's no enough threads to close the connection? I thought that it can go up to several thousands threads in thread pool, while there's about just few hundred connections to be closed.

Comment: Here is an article which should help clarifying this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vancem/diagnosing-net-core-threadpool-starvation-with-perfview-why-my-service-is-not-saturating-all-cores-or-seems-to-stall. Especially section "Why do High-scale Asynchronous Services have Problems with ThreadPool Starvation". And section about how thread pool works is worth reading

Comment: In your case, requests run on thread pool threads, and you block them by Task.WaitAll, causing mentioned thread pool starvation,  so that, as correctly mentioned above, thread pool cannot catch up and provide new threads (as it provides new threads very slowly by design) to run continuations after await to dispose connections. Long story short - never block thread pool threads, especially without very serious reason to do so

Comment: I suggest to edit the question and clarify that the connection pool exhaustion occurs under heavy load. As it stands now it is easy to trick the viewers that the problem is caused by just calling these two methods once. I have certainly been tricked myself! Also please tag the question with the type of the app (ASP.NET Core?, ASP.NET Classic?, Web API?).

Comment: @TheodorZoulias there is asp.net-core tag already. I will edit to include "heavy load".

Comment: Oops! Sorry about the tag, I should have seen that. My guess is that using `await Task.WhenAll` increases the scalability of the thread pool to a point that different bottlenecks are emerging: the pool of the database connections, and the database itself!